# Plex behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, plex

I need to use Plex Server behind nginx reverse proxy and I'm using this configuration:

```
server {
    listen                    443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/key.key;
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers               ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ecdh_curve            prime256v1:secp384r1;

    location /plex {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:32400;
    }
```

but when I call the service it replies with 401 code:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:17:53:19 +0000] "GET /plex/web/index.html HTTP/2.0" 401 82 "https://localhost/plex/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

(Both services are on own docker container in `host` network mode.)

I've also tried [this](https://github.com/toomuchio/plex-nginx-reverseproxy) nginx configuration but the result doesn't change.

Different reply is produced if I change

```
location /plex {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:32400;
    }
```

to

```
location /plex/  {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:32400/;
}
```

and the server output is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:45 +0000] "GET /plex/web/index.html HTTP/2.0" 200 11543 "https://localhost/plex/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:45 +0000] "GET /web/chunk-2-0b62ab5d252af885d778-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.css HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:45 +0000] "GET /web/js/chunk-4-60164a56fe56242806a1-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.js HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:45 +0000] "GET /web/js/chunk-2-0b62ab5d252af885d778-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.js HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:45 +0000] "GET /web/chunk-2-0b62ab5d252af885d778-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.css HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:46 +0000] "GET /web/js/chunk-4-60164a56fe56242806a1-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.js HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:46 +0000] "GET /web/js/chunk-2-0b62ab5d252af885d778-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.js HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

(If I call Plex using its URL (localhost:32400) it works fine)

Answer (score 1):

#### First off

So, I think you are really close to getting it. I went ahead and confirmed with my set up if I could use a sub-path and it appears to be working with the following plex.conf. Try it out and see if it works for you.

#### A couple things worth mentioning:

- Only use TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3
- Change ciphers accordingly
- You don't need the `error_page` section if you don't want (but will tell you if Plex server isn't running for some reason or another)
- Add some [security headers](https://securityheaders.com/)
- Turn on SSL Session Cache
- SSL Stapling (if don't have a self-signed certificate)
- Use upstream if you want (required [nginx upstream module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html))

#### What this config enables on Plex

- Can watch Live TV, Movies & Shows on Plex
- Plays TV Show theme songs
- Plays Movie trailers, extras, and featurettes

#### Finally

If you run into problems with images not displaying, media not playing, or something else that worked before, comment out the `add_header Content-Security-Policy` line and reload nginx and see if that helps.

### plex.conf

```
upstream plex {
    server localhost:32400;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name plex.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.key;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    send_timeout 100m;
    
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    # For LetsEncrypt/Certbot, you can get your chain like this: https://esham.io/2016/01/ocsp-stapling
    ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/intermediate/ocsp/cert-r3.pem;
    
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    add_header Referrer-Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin;
    add_header X-Frame-Options deny;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(self), midi=(self), sync-xhr=(self), microphone=(self), camera=(self), magnetometer=(self), gyroscope=(self), fullscreen=(self), payment=(self)";
    # Pay attention to how many domains we need to allow
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; base-uri 'self' plex.domain.com; font-src 'self' data: plex.domain.com; media-src 'self' data: blob: plex.domain.com https://*.plex.direct:32400 https://video.internetvideoarchive.net https://*.cloudfront.net; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' domain.com plex.domain.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' plex.domain.com; img-src 'self' data: blob: https: plex.domain.com; worker-src * blob:; frame-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https: domain.com plex.domain.com wss://*.plex.direct:32400 wss://pubsub.plex.tv; object-src 'self' plex.domain.com; frame-ancestors 'self' domain.com plex.domain.com; form-action 'self' plex.domain.com; manifest-src 'self' plex.domain.com; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' domain.com plex.domain.com www.gstatic.com";

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        root /path/to/503;
    }
    
    # gzip source: https://github.com/toomuchio/plex-nginx-reverseproxy/blob/master/nginx.conf
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript image/svg+xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    # Forward real ip and host to Plex
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    
    # If not using ngx_http_realip_module change '$http_x_forwarded_for,$realip_remote_addr' to $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For '$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for,$realip_remote_addr';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Extensions $http_sec_websocket_extensions;
    proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Key $http_sec_websocket_key;
    proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Version $http_sec_websocket_version;

    # Disables compression between Plex and Nginx, required if using sub_filter below.
    # May also improve loading time by a very marginal amount, as nginx will compress anyway.
    #proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

    # Buffering off send to the client as soon as the data is received from Plex.
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;

    location /plex/ {
        proxy_pass http://plex/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your latest output

```
[22/Dec/2020:18:10:45 +0000] "GET /plex/web/index.html HTTP/2.0" 200 11543 "https://localhost/plex/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
    127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:45 +0000] "GET /web/chunk-2-0b62ab5d252af885d778-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.css HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
    127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:45 +0000] "GET /web/js/chunk-4-60164a56fe56242806a1-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.js HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
    127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:45 +0000] "GET /web/js/chunk-2-0b62ab5d252af885d778-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.js HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
    127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:45 +0000] "GET /web/chunk-2-0b62ab5d252af885d778-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.css HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
    127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:46 +0000] "GET /web/js/chunk-4-60164a56fe56242806a1-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.js HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
    127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020:18:10:46 +0000] "GET /web/js/chunk-2-0b62ab5d252af885d778-plex-4.47.3-927d87d.js HTTP/2.0" 404 812 "https://localhost/plex/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

It seems like you can reach the `/plex/web/index.html`. But then when your webpage inturn is trying to find the `/web/js/....` the baseURL its using is `/` instead of `/plex`.

Referring to this answer : [How to preserve request url with nginx proxy_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834025/how-to-preserve-request-url-with-nginx-proxy-pass)

You can ask nginx to preserve the baseURL.

```
location /plex/  {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:32400;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but the system gave me the same output that I post in the end of the question

Comment: what is the root url with localhost:32400? is it  localhost:32400/plex/ or localhost:32400/ ?

Comment: `localhost/plex` is the nginx url for Plex, instead the `localhost:32400` url is the direct url to access to plex.

Comment: @LUCA: Have you succeeded to make above working? Plex needs to know somehow that it is running behind the forward proxy, so there should be Plex configuration option to set a base URL. Otherwise I believe any solution like above will fail.

Comment: @dma_k I changed the media server for this problem (and other reasons), now I'm using Emby and it works perfectly behind reverse proxy. (I tried other configurations in Plex and reverse proxy but they all failed)